# Bootstrap NavBar with JS Overlay in wordpress doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I create a site with a bootstrap template, with html it's all ok.
I use Wordpress in order to create a blog but i must have the same header and the same footer of the site clearly.
It's all ok, but the trigger doesn't open the overlay and the console says that's all ok, the overlay menu elements are present and i think the only problem is with javascript.

The site at the moment is [teknogrc.altervista.org](http://teknogrc.altervista.org)

Here you can see the HTML

```
    <header class="navbar-fixed-top s-header js__header-sticky js__header-overlay">
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div class="s-header__navbar">
            <div class="s-header__container">
                <div class="s-header__navbar-row">
                    <div class="s-header__navbar-row-col">
                        <!-- Logo -->
                        <div class="s-header__logo">
                            <a href="index.html" class="s-header__logo-link">
                                <img class="s-header__logo-img s-header__logo-img-default" src="img/logo.png" alt="TeknoGRC Logo">
                                <img class="s-header__logo-img s-header__logo-img-shrink" src="img/logo.png" alt="TeknoGRC Logo">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Logo -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="s-header__navbar-row-col">
                        <!-- Trigger -->
                        <ul style="margin-right: 70px; padding-top-top: 100px" class=" hidden-xs list-inline s-header__action s-header__action--rb">
                <li class="s-header__action-item"><a class="s-header__action-link -is-active" href="index.html">It   <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-it flag-icon-rounded"></span></a></li>
                <li class="s-header__action-item"><a class="s-header__action-link" href="index_ENG.html">En   <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb flag-icon-rounded"></span></a></li>
                <li class="s-header__action-item"><a class="s-header__action-link" href="index_DE.html">De   <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-de flag-icon-rounded"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="s-header__trigger js__trigger">
                            <span class="s-header__trigger-icon"></span>
                            <svg x="0rem" y="0rem" width="3.125rem" height="3.125rem" viewbox="0 0 54 54">
                                <circle fill="transparent" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1" cx="27" cy="27" r="25" stroke-dasharray="157 157" stroke-dashoffset="157"></circle>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                        <!-- End Trigger -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Navbar -->

        <!-- Overlay -->
        <div class="s-header-bg-overlay js__bg-overlay">
   <!-- Overlay -->
        <div class="s-header-bg-overlay js__bg-overlay">
            <!-- Nav -->
            <nav class="s-header__nav js__scrollbar">
                <div class="container-fluid">
```

Here you can see the JS code.

```
var handleOverlay = function() {
    var overlay = $('.js__bg-overlay'),
      headerOverlay = $('.js__header-overlay'),
      trigger = $('.js__trigger');
trigger.on('click', function() {
  overlay.toggleClass('-is-open');
  headerOverlay.toggleClass('-is-open');
  trigger.toggleClass('-is-active');


   });
  }
```

Someone who can help me=?

Comment: Make a fiddle for this issue

Comment: what is the issue?. site working fine for me.

Comment: teknogrc.altervista.org/news

Comment: Try ti click on the menu on the link and you can see that the menu button doesn't trigger the overlay bg in javascript.

Comment: And i have another problem, when i scroll down the page doesn't change color, from black transparent to blue.
I can't solve it, it's the last piece of puzzle.